# Mysql Php Pagination for varios table

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I have this pagination script

1 Show-page

```
$result_p = mysqli_query($conexao, "select count(*) as count FROM `banner-destaque`"); 
$row_p = mysqli_fetch_array($result_p);
$quant_resul = 10; 

        $pagina = 1; 
        $paginas = ceil($row_p['count'] / $quant_resul);
        $result = mysqli_query($conexao, "select * FROM `banner-destaque` limit 0 , " . $quant_resul);
```

The script works fine to one mysql table, but I need to reuse the same pagination script for other mysql tables with diferent sizes.

This is the table that show te results

```
<table class="flat-table flat-table-1">
    <thead>
<th>Id</th> **//Here i need get tables columns name to make it dinamically for reuse in other tables**
<th>Photo</th> 
<th>Title</th>
<th>Description</th>

    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>

<?php
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_object($result)) {   
                    echo
'
        //and here i need get all columns values to populate the above column.
    <td>'.$row->id.'</td>  
    <td>'.$row->foto.'</td>
    <td>'.$row->titulo.'</td>
    <td>'.$row->descricao.'</td>';


                };


                ?>
```

Any solution? Thanks. I'm using mysqli to connect to the database.

Answer (score 0):

make a function from the query  script and then call it passing the database table name to it as a parameter. You can then re-use this for different tables

function paginate($conexao, $tblname){

```
        $result_p = mysqli_query($conexao, "select count(*) as count FROM ".$tblname); 
        $row_p = mysqli_fetch_array($result_p);
        $quant_resul = 10; 

        $pagina = 1; 
        $paginas = ceil($row_p['count'] / $quant_resul);
        $result = mysqli_query($conexao, "select * FROM ".tblname." limit 0 , " . $quant_resul);

        return $result;
    }


    <table class="flat-table flat-table-1">
    <thead>
    <th>Id</th> **//Here i need get tables columns name to make it dinamically for reuse in other tables**
    <th>Photo</th> 
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Description</th>

        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>

    <?php
                      $result = paginate($conexao, 'banner-destaque');
                        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_object($result)) {   
                        echo
    '
            //and here i need get all columns values to populate the above column.
        <td>'.$row->id.'</td>  
        <td>'.$row->foto.'</td>
        <td>'.$row->titulo.'</td>
        <td>'.$row->descricao.'</td>';


                    };


            ?>
```

Comment: Okay, thanks, but for the <th> and <td> regions? The tables are different sizes like  1º -- ID - TITLE - PHOTO -- 2º --ID -- TITLE -- DESCRIPTION -- PHOTO --. I need get td and th accordding to the table name and table values itens.

Comment: Any solution or Other way?